# Gridset Firefox style sheet could not be loaded

Tags: html, css

Has anyone used gridset, if so have people found a problem with firefox.
i find im having a problem with the grids not working in firefox. 
Thanks.

**UPDATE**

On further inspection it seems that the style sheet can not be loaded on firefox, I am loading in the head like

```
  <link href="https://get.gridsetapp.com/35465/" rel="stylesheet">
```

can anyone see a problem ?

Comment: try and add `.da-all` to any element you should see the changes take effect in your browser. I just did on your site and it worked fine.

Comment: Hmm was that on Firefox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDN you are loading the stylesheet from isn't trusted by Firefox.

You'll need to host it somewhere else or get the host to fix the problem.

[image: CDN screenshot]

Comment: Thanks you, thats very helpful could you tell me is it just . <link href="https://get.gridsetapp.com/35465/" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> that is not trusted as its hosted externally ?

Comment: Yes, that's the URL in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes sorry, i did not see. You have answered the question, thanks.